# How to make RCP toggle button state more visible?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-indigo

I have some toggle buttons declared like this :

```
button = new Button(this, SWT.TOGGLE);
button.setImage(icon);
```

They look like this on my computer :

[image]

The right one is pushed, the left one isn't.

But on some computers, depending on the general settings of the OS, it may be hard to see if the button is pushed.

What can I do to make the button's state more visible, independently of the OS settings ?

I precise the application uses the Eclipse 3 platform and that I need this to work on any Desktop Windows starting from XP.

Comment: Create two images and update button with an appropriate one, by checking buttons state, in onSelect method of button select listener?

Comment: @AlexanderGavrilov That's a solution. I just tested it and it works. Can you change your comment to an answer ? I won't accept it if somebody gives me a cleaner and lighter solution but it will at least get a +1 (and might be a tip for future readers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I didn't find any clean solution (one which would work for all buttons without having to duplicate all icons), I did as suggested by Alexander :

```
    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        }
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            button.setImage(button.getSelection() ? pushedIcon : icon);
            ...
        }           
    });
```

It looks like this :

[image]

On computers with bad color settings (e.g. grey for selection), this will be an improvement.